# Kotlin disable metadata annotation

Tags: kotlin, proguard, obfuscation, decompiling

Is there any way to disable Kotlin metadata or just obfuscate them? It's added during compilation.
Whole code is well obfuscated but Kotlin library named "kotlin-reflect.jar" leaves method details like class name, method and parameters with type.

> @Metadata(mv = {1, 1, 13}, bv = {1, 0, 3}, k = 1, d1 = 
>   {"\000\022\n\002\030\002\n\002\030\002\n\000\n\002\020\016\n\002\b\002\030\0002\0020\001B\r\022\006\020\002\032\0020\003?\006\002\020\004R\016\020\002\032\0020\003X?\004?\006\002\n\000�\006\005"}, 
>   d2 = {"Lcom/test/SomeException;", "Lcom/test/SomeException;", "errorMessage", "", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", "build"})
>   public final class SomeException extends Exception {
>     public SomeException(@NotNull String paramString) { super(paramString); this.errorMessage = paramString; }
>     private final String errorMessage;
>   }

Comment: I think any Java .jar/.class obfuscator should work.  However, you should note that that's likely to break or significantly impact anything that depends upon method, field, and (if you obfuscate those too) class names, including reflection, dependency injection, logs, stack traces, &c.  And it can't stop people decompiling the code itself.

Comment: Finally used R8 instead Proguard with same rules and it worked on dexing step, but same classes still have this annotation with class, method and parameters details. I think that's huge security gap in Kotlin language and should be fixed somehow.
Not sure if this metadata are still in use, as real names are not longer used in code.

Comment: We don't know what your R8/ProGuard rules are, e.g. if your `keep` rules are too broad.

Comment: @Michael This is definitely not about `keep` rules. 
As mentioned above - Metadata is removed in dexing step (part of apk build).

Answer (score 1):

I’ve created 'unmeta', an Android Gradle plug-in that removes all Kotlin `@Metadata` and `@DebugMetadata` annotations for release builds.

You can find it here: https://github.com/oliver-jonas/unmeta

It uses ASM and operates directly on the compiled bytecode.